# iPhone Game Development

Tags: iphone

I am starting iPhone Development, I have already made 1 app with c and objective-c, but the reason why i started was to make games for myself...

What is the best language for beginners to make iphone games?

I know there are a bunch of options, but which would you suggest for a beginner?

Thank You

-Techy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there aren't many options at all for iPhone Development. You're locked into Objective-C, but you can also use C and C++ code in your app.

That said, there have been some people tinkering with getting C# on it but I don't know how all of that works. It's being backed by the guys at Mono Project for use in the [Unity 3D Engine](http://unity3d.com/). Check out [Podcast #61](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/podcast-61/). Miguel De Icaza is the guest and he talks about how they are accomplishing this.

Sorry if I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

You say there are a bunch of options, but it seems to me that Objective-C and C are the clear choices. You can toss C++ in there too, of course.

Maybe you're talking about game systems like Unity, Torque, and Cocos-2D?

Comment: no, I have tried those, but I feel guilty that their are other people out ther actually taking months to program games while I cheat...

Comment: Well, I certainly don't want you to cheat. Maybe ARM assembly language is for you.